# ready queue(why queue specifically)?

Tags: queue, scheduling

I have been wondering why ready queue,that we have in Operating systems is called a queue?I have studied various scheduling algorithms like round robin,priority scheduling,etc but only first come first serve uses the ready queue as a queue(implementingFIFO policy).

For example in priority scheduling if two processes arrive at different times while CPU is executing some third process,then after it is done,it will choose the process with higher priority.I feel it is kind of violation of FIFO policy used in Queues,i.e,first in first out.

So do we just call it a queue for the sake of calling it,or is there a deeper logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still called a queue because if there are two processes with the same priority, the process which was placed on the queue first will be executed first just like in a normal FIFO queue.